# Manually Install Android Plugin

Tags: android, svg, android-gradle-plugin

I heard about an awesome plugin called Victor made by Dan Lew from Trello. The point of the plugin is to use `.svg` files for resources. The plugin converts them all to `.png` in all of the densities needed for different screen resolutions. This is awesome for me because I have a bunch of AnimationDrawables in my app and now I don't have to make different copies of every single frame I have in my animations. The only problem is that I don't know how to get it to work.

Here's the link to github [here](https://github.com/trello/victor)

There's not much in the documentation, so I was expecting it to be easy to setup. I'm pretty sure I setup the `build.gradle` correctly.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.trello:victor:0.1.5'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.trello.victor'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.firsttread.anthony.victor"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        svg.srcDir 'src/main/svg'
    }
 }

}

victor {
    // Any assets defined in relative terms needs a base DPI specified
    svgDpi = 72

    // Do not generate these densities for SVG assets
    excludeDensities = [ 'ldpi', 'xxxhdpi' ]
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

The plugin can't be found in the plugin search in Android Studio. I downloaded Victor from github and tried to get the plugin from disk, but when I navigated to the folder there wasn't an option to select.

I was looking through the Android folders and noticed that one of the other plugins I installed through the AS plugin installer was put in `.AndroidStudio1.5/system`, so I put the Victor folder there and rebuilt gradle with the code in it and got no errors, but when I try to run the code it doesn't recognize the drawables (the `.svg` files) at runtime.

Based on their example in the repository, I made a svg folder under app. It doesn't seem to be in the res directory. Then I added the `.svg` files in there, but gradle is still not recognizing the svg format, and I think it's supposed to now.

IDK if I messed up installing Victor or if I'm just not using it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install anything to Android Studio.  It's not a plugin for Android Studio. It's a "plugin" for the build process.  Gradle will download and run the plugin at build time.

The first place to start is where you put the SVG files.  In the build.gradle file, you have the location of the SVG files specified as `src/main/svg`.  But it sounds like you are not putting them there.  You said you put them in the `res` folder.  Start by fixing that.  Try moving them into `src/main/svg`.